# Turn a snippet of HTML and PHP into a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

the code is

```
<div class="huili-relevant-left">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,"taobao_value",true);?>" hidefocus="true" target="_blank" class="btn-buy js-log " data-log="page=p-huihui-discount-detail&type=buy">
                        <b>￥<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,"price_value",true);?></b>
                        <i>buy</i>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

the has two Custom Fields is `taobao_value` `and price_value`
now I want become a shortcode
Please help me

Answer (score 3):

When you want to turn a snippet into a shortcode, you have to *return* a string. You cannot use `echo` or print anything in any other way.

Also, always escape your data, and check if there are actually values.

I have used the [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) here, because it is easy to read:

```
add_shortcode( 'taobao', 'taobao_shortcode' );

function taobao_shortcode()
{
    $taobao = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "taobao_value", true ) );
    $price  = esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "price_value", true ) );

    if ( ! $taobao or ! $price )
        return;

    return <<<SHORTCODE
    <div class="huili-relevant-left">
        <a href="$taobao" 
            hidefocus="true" 
            target="_blank" 
            class="btn-buy js-log" 
            data-log="page=p-huihui-discount-detail&type=buy"
        >
            <b>￥ $price</b>
            <i>buy</i>
        </a>
    </div>
SHORTCODE;
}
```

You can insert the value into your posts now with `[taobao]`.